# Multiple newpages --- after several large tables

Tags: tables, page-breaking

How to effectively apply multiple \newpage --- after several large tables

```
\newpage 
\newpage 
\newpage 
\newpage
```

In one of my sections (say Section 1), there are many large Tables but some texts. In the next Section 2, I want to start the Section 2 after many page breaks after all these tables.

> Somehow multiple \newpage do not work out. Any new method to excuse page breaks in this case? Please suggest the new commands and tricks.

p.s there is no minimal MWE because it is just a simple scenario stated above that we need to know some new commands and tricks.

Thank you!

Comment: `\newpage~ 
\newpage~ 
\newpage~ 
\newpage`

Comment: Are you looking for `\clearpage` instead that will flush all processed floats?

Comment: thanks +1 clearpage works